# SQLITE - INSERT does not return error but no data is inserted

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I am attempting to insert data into a local SQLITE database file from a C# application. The transaction does not throw any errors but the data is not inserted. The same insert statement works from within a query analyzer.

Do I need to perform a commit? Is there a Commit method?

Command's transaction property is null..

```
  var command = new SQLiteCommand(insert.BuildInsert(tableName,keyValuePairs),Connection);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

UPDATE:

I have also tried to assciate my SQLiteCommand with a SQLiteTransaction but have had no luck.

```
try
        {
            SQLiteTransaction liteTransaction = Connection.BeginTransaction();
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(insert.BuildInsert(tableName, keyValuePairs), Connection);
            command.Transaction = liteTransaction;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            liteTransaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e)
        {
            //error
            connection.Close();
        }
```

The BuildInsert method just constructs a string that is the INSERT. The insert works fine in a query analyzer.

```
public  string BuildInsert(string tableName, IDictionary<string, string> testDataDic)
    {
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(String.Format("INSERT INTO {0} ", tableName));
        AddColumns(stringBuilder,testDataDic.Keys);
        AddValues(stringBuilder, testDataDic.Values);

        return stringBuilder.ToString();

    }
```

This is an example of the INSERT statement. This works fine outside of the code but does not throw any errors:

```
INSERT INTO TestData (walking,running,image,yoga,exercise,meditation,hobby,somethingelse,howoften,numtechniques,userreturn,chosentechnique,chosentechnique)VALUES ("true","I will try to use deep breathing.","false","true","false","false","true","true","When I'm stressed","1","true","deepbreathing","deepbreathing"); COMMIT;
```

Comment: post code to see how you are trying

Comment: I would like to see the code for the BuildInsert method.  Maybe something is not quite right in that.

Comment: Okay, now does your AddColumns make all the columns are in ()?  Like insert into Users(Username, Password)? - and does it make sure that there are no extra commas?  Same for AddValues, does build the query right?  What's a sample return value from BuildInsert?

Comment: @thorkia I have added an example of the insert statement. I really doubt this is the problem. This insert works fine when put into the query analyzer and does not report an error from the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOH! So the local database build operation was set to 'Always copu' I have multiple versions of the same file.

Sorry for that. That's lame.